# Hosting site doesn't allow me to make downloadable link

Tags: hosting

I created a website in 000 web host , It's free host, and I uploaded an .apk file into that host, now i want that when I type the url in the browser the file should start downloading automatically, but it doesn't start, It has some restriction on this type of files, how can i do it with html or javascript , please help

Comment: There isn't really enough information here for us to help you debug this. Can you give more information? Please also read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Does your host let you edit MIME types?

I had to do this at a different host for .dmg files (Mac Disk Images).

```
File Name Extension: .apk
MIME Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Comment: I contacted them and they told me it has restrictions that doesn;t allow me to do that, how to change MIME types, i don't know